# Vector field Streamline on sphere

Tags: matlab, vector, geometry, field

I have the probelm connected with vector field on sphere. I have six 2d arrays: first three for coordinates and second three for vector components.
I need to draw streamlines of this vector field on sphere. I have tried streamlines and streamslice, but they dont support spherical surfacec. Do you have any suggestions how I can plost streamlines of this vector field?

Answer (score 2):

First define the flow arena with meshgrid. This creates a 3D array of points at which the velocity magnitudes and directions can be calculated.

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(-1.01:0.02:1.01,-1.01:0.02:1.01,-1.01:0.02:1.01);
```

Define your flow parameters.

```
U = 1; % x-wise free stream velocity
a = 0.5; % sphere radius
mu = -2*pi*a^3*U; % doublet strength required to create spherical streamlines
```

The x,y,z velocity components for an x-wise (streamwise) doublet superimposed with an x-direction flow is:

```
ux = U+mu.*(2.*x.^2-y.^2-z.^2)./(4*pi.*(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2).^(5/2));
uy = 3*mu.*x.*y./(4*pi.*(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2).^(5/2));
uz = 3*mu.*x.*z./(4*pi.*(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2).^(5/2));
```

The start point of the streamlines needs to be defined. For this case a small 2D mesh of points on the upstream side of the flow field centred around the stagnation streamline is a good choice.

```
[startx, starty, startz] = meshgrid(-1,-0.1:0.02:0.1,-0.1:0.02:0.1);
```

Generate the streamline plot.

```
streamline(x,y,z,ux,uy,uz,startx,starty,startz)
```

The result looks a bit like an onion but represents the 3D potential flow around a sphere.